# Let $g$ be a function from $(0, 1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\int_0^1 g^2(x)dx$ finite. Does this imply that $\int_0^1 g(x)dx$ is finite?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, inequality

Let $g$ be a function from $(0, 1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\int_0^1 g^2(x)dx$ finite. Does this imply that $\int_0^1 g(x)dx$ is finite?

So I know that $| \int_0^1 g(x)dx | \leq \int_0^1 |g(x)|dx = \int_0^1 \sqrt{g^2(x)}dx$. Not sure how to continue.

Comment: a) Cauchy-Schwarz, $\int_0^1 \lvert g(x)\rvert\,dx \leqslant \sqrt{\int_0^1 1^2\,dx}\cdot \sqrt{\int_0^1 g(x)^2\,dx}$, b) $2\lvert g(x)\rvert \leqslant 1 + g(x)^2$.

Comment: Hint: Replacing the values where $\lvert g(x) \rvert < 1$ with $g(x) = 1$ won't change whether the integral diverges.  What can you then say about $g(x)$ as compared to $g^2(x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $(\int fg)^2\le \int f^2\int g^2$, for $F=1$ and $G=g$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A$ be a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$ and put
$$g(x):=\cases{1\quad & $(x\notin A)$ \cr -1 & $(x\in A)$\cr}\ .$$
Then $g$ is not even integrable, but $\int_0^1 g^2(x)\ dx=1$. Therefore we better assume $g$ measurable to begin with. Under these circumstances
$$\left(\int_0^1 |g(x)|\cdot 1\ dx\right)^2\leq \int_0^1 g^2(x)\ dx \int_0^1 1^2\ dx<\infty$$
by Schwarz' inequality and assumption. This implies the existence of the integral $\int_0^1 g(x)\ dx$.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a more elementary proof (insofar as it doesn't use Cauchy-Schwarz).

Let $A = \{x: |g(x)| \geq 1\}$. Then 
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} |g(x)| \, dx &= \int_{A} |g(x)|\, dx + \int_{(0,1)-A} |g(x)|\, dx \\
&\leq \int_{A} |g(x)|^{2}\, dx + \int_{(0,1)-A} |g(x)|\, dx \\
&\leq \int_{0}^{1} |g(x)|^{2}\, dx + 1 \\
&< \infty.
\end{align*}
$$